# Seeing escape characters in cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, ccm

When typing commands in cqlsh, almost all keys are not escaped. For example, arrow keys produce:

`cqlsh> ^[[C^[[C^[[D^[[D^[[C^[[C^[[D^[[D`

Escape produces:

`cqlsh> ^[^[^[^[^[`

etc.

I did some digging and some people are saying that it's because the python 'readline' package is not installed (cqlsh is really a python shell), but after pip installing readline, the escape characters are still printed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the problem was with pyenv. The solution is to `brew update && brew upgrade`, then uninstall/install all python versions installed with pyenv.